# Tune Elastic Write Performance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I am trying to save (and index) 170GB file (~915 millions rows and 25 columns) in Elasticsearch cluster. I got a horrible performance on a 5 nodes elasticsearch cluster. The task takes ~5hours.
Spark cluster has 150 Cores 10x(15 CPU, 64 RAM).

This is my current worflow:

- Build a Spark Dataframe from multiple parquet files from S3.
- Then save this dataframe to ElasticSearch index using "*org.elasticsearch.spark.sql*" source from **Spark**. (I tried many **sharding** and **replication** configuration mix without gaining in performance)

**This is the Cluster nodes caracteristics**

- 5 nodes (16 CPU, 64 RAM, 700GB DISK) each.
- HEAP_SIZE is about 50% of availabe RAM, means 32GB on each node. Configured in /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options

This is the code which writes the dataframe to ElasticSearch(wrote in scala)

```
 writeDFToEs(whole_df, "main-index")
```

The **writeDFToEs** function:

```
  def writeDFToEs(df: DataFrame, index: String) = {
    df.write
      .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
      .option("es.nodes", "192.168.1.xxx")
      .option("es.http.timeout", 600000)
      .option("es.http.max_content_length", "2000mb")
      .option("es.port", 9200)
      .mode("overwrite")
      .save(s"$index")

  }
```

Can you help me finf  out what I am not doing well and how to fi it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi, interesting might be of interest https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html

Comment: @jspcal thanks a lot for your input.
 I already tried almost all elements of list without any improvement.

**Use auto-generated ids** and **Unset or increase the refresh interval** are the ones remaining, as I have no option to upgrade the hardware. I will try these right now.

Comment: I don't know scala, but it doesn't look like you are using `_bulk` to index?

Comment: @warkolm I am using a connector that implicitly index with `_bulk`.  It loads 1000 documents at once. Please check the source I loaded in **format** option `org.elasticsearch.spark.sql`.

Comment: I would try adjusting your bulk batch size as a first step, increase and then decrease it to see if it helps

Comment: @warkolm you were right. After running a bunch of tests again, (testing various values) for `_bulk`, I finally got better results (still not optimal though)  with `es.batch.size.entries` set to **10000** and following values in ES index template.



`{
  "index": {
    "number_of_shards": "10",
    "number_of_replicas": "0",
    "refresh_interval": "60s"
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answering my own question.**

As suggested by @warkolm, I focused on `_bulk`.

I am using **es-hadoop** connector, so I had to tweak `es.batch.size.entries` parameter.

After running a bunch of tests, (testing various values), I finally got better results (still not optimal though) with `es.batch.size.entries` set to **10000** and following values in ES index template.

```
{
  "index": {
    "number_of_shards": "10",
    "number_of_replicas": "0",
    "refresh_interval": "60s"
  }
}
```

Finally, my `df.write`looks like this:

```
    df.write
      .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
      .option("es.nodes", es_nodes)
      .option("es.port", es_port)
      .option("es.http.timeout", 600000)
      .option("es.batch.size.entries", 10000)
      .option("es.http.max_content_length", "2000mb")
      .mode("overwrite")
      .save(s"$writeTo")
```

**Now the process takes ~3h (2h 55 min) instead of 5 hours.**

I am still improving the configs and code. I will update if I got better performance.